# Increase stack size using mingw in qt5

Tags: windows, qt, stack, mingw

Hi guys,

I'm trying to increase the stack size of my g++. I need a 4 dimensions matrix ( 600*600*600*600 of int). I tried adding these 2 lines in my .pro file, but unfortunately it didn't work.

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--stack,4194304

LIBS += -Wl,--stack,4194304

Comment: Did you calculate that out? it would be about 518GB!!! I don't think you can get enough memory for this, no matter if you use a stack or the heap...

Comment: Your shure? 600*600*600*600*4 = 518,400,000,000

Comment: I was talking about 4194304 xD

Comment: Ah okay ;) but 4MB wont solve the problem if you need over 500GB to create that matrix ;)

Comment: What OS are you using? and what compiler?, In windows / gcc I think the default is 8mb for a process. Also Felix is right, except for the last mult by 4, so its about 130GB!, you could try to dynamically allocate it and just pass pointers around (if you have enough memory!)

Comment: @code_fodder ```sizeof(int) ``` is 4 Byte on most systems, so its 518......Byte, thats roughly about 483 Gigabyte.

Comment: You should think about a possibility to split your matrix into smaller chunks (for example having chunks with a side-len of 128)

Comment: Yeah, that's what i taught at first, but this 4 dimensions matrix is a hashtable.